# Twitter bootstrap datepicker in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building an application with twitter bootstrap,Angular js and Taffy DB.

javascript:

```
  $(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });

   $scope.submit = function () {
   console.log($scope.eventdate);
   };
```

HTML:

```
<label for="eventdate">Date</label>
    <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker"  data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="20" type="text" id="eventdate" ng-model="eventdate">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
```

But `console.log($scope.eventdate);` is undefined.

Please advice

Comment: Not this way. You cannot mix jquery and angularjs. Look at angular-ui bootstrap components here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. Basically you need to have a directive for this.

Answer (score 19):

If you decided to use Angular, put `datepicker` into directive:

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.var1 = '12-07-2013';
});


app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd-MM-yyyy',
           language: 'en',
           pickTime: false,
           startDate: '01-11-2013',      // set a minimum date
           endDate: '01-11-2030'          // set a maximum date
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       var1={{var1}}
      <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
      <div class="well">
        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
          <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></input>
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KsK5F1M2zrv0SDTwRM4N?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Somehow the calendar is not popping up in my form. Do you need momentjs for this ?

Answer (score 6):

Why not use this: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . It has all the bootstrap modules created as Angular directives, thus no need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps, I was looking for a simple example, but I couldn't find it, I found one but full of code and links and I cleaned it, here is the most simple working example of datepicker using angular bootstrap:

---> [sample page](http://lionfishtechnologies.com/developers/samples/angular_bootstrap_datepicker/datePicker.html) <---

Comment: You're not even using it in a directive? You just wrapped around a controller that doesn't exist? Am I missing something?

Comment: this is a broken link

Answer (score -2):

Use the Angular [directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) for jquery datepicker

[Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-date/)

Comment: To be precise, this is not an Angular directive, but a directive from the third-party angular-ui library.