# AngularJS directive for calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm migrating an existing site to AngularJS and I'm having trouble with Boostraps's datepicker.

HTML:

```
<div id="calendar" class="pull-right"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#calendar').on('changeDate', function(event) {
    window.location.href = '/appointments?date=' + event.format();
});
```

I've tried writing a directive like this but it's not working.

HTML

```
<div id="calendar" class="pull-right" datepicker></div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.datepicker({
                onChangeDate: function() {
                  ...
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you need jquery to add bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Try the [Angular UI Bootstrap directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup) - they were specifically made for Angular and remove the dependency on the full jQuery library.

Comment: for your reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966319/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966319/twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-in-angular-js) worked for me.

```
app.directive('datetimez', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.datetimepicker({
      ...
      }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        ...
      });
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

include jquery into you project then

```
.directive('datepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                onChangeDate: function() {
                  ...
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```